# ASP.NET MVC - Is partial view the right place to check if model is null or empty?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I have the following partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Foo>

<div id="foo">
    @foreach (var foo in Model)
    {
        ...
    }
</div>
```

If collection is null or empty, I'd like to display some user friendly message, otherwise I'd like to list all collection items. Shell I make that check inside partial view, or inside calling method? What the best practice in this case and why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the partial view is the right place - the reason to use a partial view is so your page only needs the view name and a reference to the collection. If you add the IsEmpty logic to the top level page you lose that encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% familiar with Razor syntax, but I would create UI helper for that. To keep View simple I use following "rules": if I ever get if statement or a loop then I'll create UI helper.

I have static class for each context. Let's say I have a music store.. then I would have class called AlbumHelper

```
public static class AlbumHelper : {possible inheritance\
{
    public static string CreateAlbumList(Model model)
    {
        // TODO: create list here using technique you prefer
        // <ul><li>empty</li></ul>
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

That one I would call using (remember to add namespace to your Web.config):

```
<%= AlbumHelper.CreateAlbumList(Model) %>
```

If it would be commonly used *control* then I would create extension, so that it would be created using this line.

```
<%= Html.AlbumList(Model) %>
```

[Here is a link](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=406&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) to short tutorial for creating extension

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It's a bit different with Razor - helpers look a lot like partial views and can be defined locally. Also the cleaner syntax means it makes more sense to write the helper as cshtml which will get converted to code similar to your example.

Comment: @Tom Clarkson Okay, I'll understand. My answer applies only to the "traditional" View engine